# what are the benefits of using s3 bucket with cognito aws service?

Tags: reactjs, amazon-s3, amazon-cognito

I want to fetch files/ Records from s3 bucket on client side. So i implemented code in react js.

But now i want to use cognito service with s3 bucket for security reason in my application. So please suggest me how will it work to get file from the bucket.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Are you looking give users access to only their own files?

Comment: yes @NinadGaikwad

Comment: just now i have passes IdentityPoolId as an credential at client side and now i am able to get all files/data from s3 bucket

Comment: Is is safe to expose IdentityPoolId at client side?

Comment: It is safe since even if an attacker gets hold of it they still have to know credentials to make any authenticated calls.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a policy to ensure user is only able to access their own "folder" in s3. You will have to use `sub` which is a identity pool variable (kind of like user's unique id). You can get this id using the [getId](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognitoidentity/latest/APIReference/API_GetId.html) API to get this sub variable. Then you put it in the s3 path whenever making get and put calls so that user can access objects on this path. 
You can see the policy example of this [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_examples_s3_cognito-bucket.html)